# How to read every 3 lines in perl?

Tags: perl

Sorry for the bad English

I have a txt file like this:

```
id: 1
name: a
sex: m
id: 2
name: b
sex: f
```

so I would like to read every 3 lines of this file to an array

```
[ { id =>1, name => a, sex => m }, { id=>2, name=>b, sex=>f}]
```

How to read every 3 lines in perl?

Comment: You can read it by line and split on ": ", when the first part is "id" you store the previous hash reference in your array and you start a new hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does what you ask:

```
my @recs;
while (!eof()) {
   my %rec;
   for (1..3) {
      chomp( my $line = <> );
      my ($key, $val) = split(/:\s*/, $line, 2);
      $rec{$key} = $val;
   }

   push @recs, \%rec;
}
```

And so does the following:

```
my @recs;
my $rec;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($key, $val) = split(/:\s*/, $_, 2);
   if ($. % 3 == 1) {
      $rec = {};
      push @recs, $rec;
   }

   $rec->{$key} = $val;
}
```

However, I think it would be best to rely on records starting with the `id` key-value.

```
my @recs;
my $rec;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($key, $val) = split(/:\s*/, $_, 2)
   if ($key eq 'id') {
      $rec = {};
      push @recs, $rec;
   }

   $rec->{$key} = $val;
}
```

Comment: `$rec = {}; push @recs, $rec;` can be written more concisely as `push @recs, $rec = {};` (which permits a switch from an `if` statement to an `if` statement modifier), but the latter is less clear.

Comment: Since there's nothing wrong, care to delete your comment saying there is? You just made `$rec` anonymous and duplicated some code.