# Copying the contents of a hash into another larger hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, associative

I'm working on a configuration parser for a config file that includes an unknown number of various objects, all with their own field/value pairs.

Config file looks something like this:

```
ObjectType1
  name Alpha
  host 127.0.0.1
ObjectType1
  name Beta
  host 10.11.12.13
ObjectType2
  name AlphaPolicy
  type This
  useExtraWidgets true
```

So I'm trying to parse each individual object into a hash of fields/values, which works great. What's tripping me up is that I then want each of those individual objects added into a larger hash that holds the whole configuration. This larger hash should have an array for each object type, that holds the fields/values for one particular object. I simply can't figure out how to push my hash of fields/values onto the larger hash in a sensible way.

Here's some pseudocode with comments -- can somebody help me with where I need @s, $s, brackets, etc.? I call it pseudocode because it doesn't actually work. It prints nothing. Thanks.

```
my %hash1,%hash2;

$hash2{'name'} = "Alpha";
$hash2{'host'} = "127.0.0.1";
push @{$hash1{'ObjectType1'}}, %hash2;

undef %hash2;

$hash2{'name'} = "Beta";
$hash2{'host'} = "10.11.12.13";
push @{$hash1{'ObjectType1'}}, %hash2;

undef %hash2;

$hash2{'name'} = "AlphaPolicy";
$hash2{'type'} = "this";
$hash2{'useExtraWidgets'} = "true";
push @{$hash1{'ObjectType2'}}, %hash2;

print $hash1{'ObjectType1'}[0]{'name'}; #I want this to print "Alpha"
print $hash1{'ObjectType1'}[1]{'host'}; #I want this to print "10.11.12.13"
print $hash1{'ObjectType2'}[0]{'name'}; #I want this to print "AlphaPolicy"
```

Comment: Note that you should invent better names than `%hash1` and `%hash2` for your variables.

Comment: Oh yes, definitely. This is just an artificial test case I put together.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that the sample "artificial" code that you write here for the world's consumption has very poor identifiers while the final code that will be read by only yourself and a few others will (presumably) have "proper" names.

Comment: You might take a look at ikegami's [third solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288627/how-to-read-every-3-lines-in-perl/37289263#37289263) which is almost what you could do (with a couple of modifications).

Answer (score 0):

When you're nesting data structures in Perl, you need to store references to the structures rather than the structures themselves. You take a reference to a variable in Perl by escaping the sigil, e.g.:

```
my (%hash1, %hash2);

$hash2{'name'} = "Alpha";
$hash2{'host'} = "127.0.0.1";
push @{$hash1{'ObjectType1'}}, \%hash2; # n.b. the \
```

When you later try to access these values, you'll have to dereference them with the arrow infix operator (`->`):

```
say $hash1{ObjectType1}->[0]->{name};
```

In other words, dereference the array stored at `$hash1{ObjectType1}` and take the first element; dereference the hash stored at that element and take the `name` key. Modern Perls let you collapse and even omit (in some cases, I think as long as the "head" isn't itself a reference) arrow infix operators, so depending on your version, this should work:

```
say $hash1{ObjectType1}->[0]{name};
```

And possibly even this:

```
say $hash1{ObjectType1}[0]{name};
```

I would highly recommend reading [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)[[tut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)], [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html), and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) when you have some time!

Comment: *"When you later try to access these values, you'll have to dereference them with the arrow infix operator"* That isn't necessary. Arrows between closing and opening braces or square brackets are optional, and the syntax that the OP has asked for will work fine.

Comment: Thanks -- I last truly studied Perl about 15 years ago in college, and just use it for little scripts here and there now. It is mostly a functional level of knowledge but it gets iffy when I have to use pointers, arrow operators, etc. This clarifies things greatly, and I appreciate the links for further reading too.