# Transposing long list of numbers

Tags: r, perl, transpose

I have an Excel CSV file with a long list of numbers in a single column, separated by an empty space:

`6.83E-05
1.93E-04
4.36E-04
7.17E-04
1.04E-03
1.37E-03
1.30E-03
1.39E-03
1.34E-03
1.34E-03
1.58E-03
1.30E-03
8.82E-04
1.09E-03
9.61E-04
8.19E-04
7.03E-04
6.21E-04
5.54E-04
4.98E-04`

`2.56E-05
7.33E-05
1.63E-04
2.63E-04
3.79E-04
5.03E-04
4.83E-04
5.45E-04
5.76E-04
6.33E-04
8.06E-04
7.36E-04
5.43E-04
6.69E-04
6.12E-04
5.36E-04
4.66E-04
4.13E-04
3.66E-04
3.27E-04`

I want to re-organize it so they appear like this:

`6.83E-05  2.56E-05
1.93E-04    7.33E-05
4.36E-04    1.63E-04
7.17E-04    2.63E-04
1.04E-03    3.79E-04
1.37E-03    5.03E-04
1.30E-03    4.83E-04
1.39E-03    5.45E-04
1.34E-03    5.76E-04
1.34E-03    6.33E-04
1.58E-03    8.06E-04
1.30E-03    7.36E-04
8.82E-04    5.43E-04
1.09E-03    6.69E-04
9.61E-04    6.12E-04
8.19E-04    5.36E-04
7.03E-04    4.66E-04
6.21E-04    4.13E-04
5.54E-04    3.66E-04
4.98E-04    3.27E-04`

I'm looking to do this with Perl or R.  Would the R transpose function work in this case?  I tried awk, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: once see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000380/splitting-dataframes-in-r-based-on-empty-rows

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perl solution adapted by another question (solution by ikegami). It outputs a csv file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::UtilsBy::XS 'zip_by';

# adapted method by ikegami
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288627/how-to-read-every-3-lines-in-perl/37289263#37289263

my @in = split /\n/, <<EOF;
6.83E-05
1.93E-04
4.36E-04
7.17E-04
1.04E-03
1.37E-03
1.30E-03
1.39E-03
1.34E-03
1.34E-03
1.58E-03
1.30E-03
8.82E-04
1.09E-03
9.61E-04
8.19E-04
7.03E-04
6.21E-04
5.54E-04
4.98E-04

2.56E-05
7.33E-05
1.63E-04
2.63E-04
3.79E-04
5.03E-04
4.83E-04
5.45E-04
5.76E-04
6.33E-04
8.06E-04
7.36E-04
5.43E-04
6.69E-04
6.12E-04
5.36E-04
4.66E-04
4.13E-04
3.66E-04
3.27E-04
EOF

my $rec = [];
my @data = $rec;

for (@in) {
    if (/^\s*$/) {
        $rec = [];
        push @data, $rec;
    }
    else {
        push @$rec, $_;
    }
}   

print zip_by { join(",", @_) . "\n"} @data;
```

**Update:** Turns out to be a simpler solution given the changed input. (89 rows and ~171 cols)

```
my @data;
my $i = 0;

for (@in) {
    if (/^\s*$/) {
        $i = 0;
    }
    else {
        push @{ $data[$i++] }, $_;
    }
}   

for my $aref (@data) {
    print join(",", @$aref), "\n";  
}
```

Output:

```
6.83E-05,2.56E-05
1.93E-04,7.33E-05
4.36E-04,1.63E-04
7.17E-04,2.63E-04
1.04E-03,3.79E-04
1.37E-03,5.03E-04
1.30E-03,4.83E-04
1.39E-03,5.45E-04
1.34E-03,5.76E-04
1.34E-03,6.33E-04
1.58E-03,8.06E-04
1.30E-03,7.36E-04
8.82E-04,5.43E-04
1.09E-03,6.69E-04
9.61E-04,6.12E-04
8.19E-04,5.36E-04
7.03E-04,4.66E-04
6.21E-04,4.13E-04
5.54E-04,3.66E-04
4.98E-04,3.27E-04
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are quite certain that you want the first half of the entries in column 1 and the second half in column two, you could do this with `matrix`.

```
Input = read.csv("Input.csv", header=FALSE)
M = matrix(Input$V1, ncol=2)
          [,1]     [,2]
 [1,] 6.83e-05 2.56e-05
 [2,] 1.93e-04 7.33e-05
 [3,] 4.36e-04 1.63e-04
 [4,] 7.17e-04 2.63e-04
 [5,] 1.04e-03 3.79e-04
 [6,] 1.37e-03 5.03e-04
 [7,] 1.30e-03 4.83e-04
 [8,] 1.39e-03 5.45e-04
 [9,] 1.34e-03 5.76e-04
[10,] 1.34e-03 6.33e-04
[11,] 1.58e-03 8.06e-04
[12,] 1.30e-03 7.36e-04
[13,] 8.82e-04 5.43e-04
[14,] 1.09e-03 6.69e-04
[15,] 9.61e-04 6.12e-04
[16,] 8.19e-04 5.36e-04
[17,] 7.03e-04 4.66e-04
[18,] 6.21e-04 4.13e-04
[19,] 5.54e-04 3.66e-04
[20,] 4.98e-04 3.27e-04
```

If you want to write it back out to a csv with the new structure, you can use:

```
write.table(M, "Input2.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  So using R I ran:

`Input = read.csv("RawOutput.csv", header=FALSE)
M = matrix(Input$V1, nrow= 89, ncol=171)`

And it gave me the output I wanted, 89 rows and 171 columns.  However there may be some input files of different lengths.  They may require more or less than 171 columns (they will always have 89 rows though).

Is there a way to tell R to stop processing the input CSV when it reaches a marker (eg. puttng "EOF" in the final cell)?  Otherwise it will loop around to the beginning again and keep adding columns up to whatever number is specified with ncol.

Comment: If you do not know the number of rows, but it will always be 89 columns, use `nrow= 89` but do not specify  `ncol`